# NP and verifiability equivalence - does this guarantee that any certificate can be verified in polynomial time?

Tags: turing-machines, np, nondeterminism

As a follow-up from my old question [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/58154/51868), I'm wondering more about the equivalence proof. Intuitively, NP has been described as the class of all problems which a solution certificate can be verified in polynomial time. Let's say we have a problem $K$ in NP and we have a certificate $c_e$ obtained externally that proves a YES or NO result for $x$.

From my understanding of the proof implications, if we have a NTM which solves $K$ in polynomial time, this implies that there exists a verifier for $K$ which takes any certificate and says whether that specific certificate is a valid "solution" for if $x$ results in YES/NO. The proof involves the fact that the NTM generates its own certificate $c_n$ which the verifier then uses, but this has nothing to do with $c_e$ from what I see. From my understanding, the verifier should take any arbitrary certificate (including $c_e$) and verifies that it indeed leads to the answer. But instead, the verifier uses only the certificate $c_n$ created by the NTM to verify whether $x$ results in YES/NO. In other words, the verifier isn't able to check any arbitrary certificate - it's only able to check the one created by the NTM.

To rephrase in case I'm not making sense – constructing a verifier, in my interpretation, means this verifier can take any certificate and check whether it's a proof for $x$. But the equivalence proof has the verifier take a specific certificate $c_n$ created by the NTM and only checks whether that is a valid proof for $x$. So what makes the verifier able to  verify for any arbitrary certificate $c_e$?

I must be getting confused somewhere. Is there any point which labels my misunderstanding? I'd really like to fully grasp the intuition of the proof.

Answer (score 2):

A non-deterministic Turing machine has a special instruction that allows it to non-deterministically "guess" a bit. The list of bits guessed by the machine is sometimes called a *certificate*. You can imagine that the guessed bits are taken from an auxiliary tape, whose contents you can think of as a certificate.

Here is an example. Consider the problem SAT: the input is a formula, and wish to find out whether the formula is satisfiable. A non-deterministic Turing machine for this problem "guesses" an assignment, and then checks ("verifies") that it satisfies the given formula. Alternatively, the machine gets a certificate and verifies that it is a satisfying assignment for the input formula. This is exactly the same Turing machine, only the process of non-deterministic guessing is visualized as reading from an auxiliary input, which we think of as a certificate.

Comment: Thank you Yuval - I think I understand this part, but I'm not quite sure about an arbitrary certificate. If the machine receives a certificate, let's say $c_e$, how does the proof of equivalence demonstrate this exactly? That's more where I'm confused.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by an arbitrary certificate. The certificate just specifies the guesses of the machine. There is no freedom beyond that.

Comment: sorry, I should've been more clear with that. So going along with SAT, the verifier will take a boolean formula as input along with a certificate, which in this case would be a set of true/false values. Now there may be multple sets of true/false values that satisfy a boolean formula. So thus there's the possibility of multiple valid certificates for a satisfiable problem with a given input. Say that I come up with certificate $c_e$. I'm wondering how are we ensured that a verifier created from an NTM is able to verify my certificate? The NTM could possibly guess a different certificate.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having more than one valid certificate. There isn't any canonical valid certificate - all valid certificates have the same status.

Comment: So let's say I have an invalid certificate I present to the verifier. By the equivalence proof, we construct an NTM. NTM comes up with a correct certificate. Verifier uses that correct certificate created by the NTM to verify the solution. So even though I presented an invalid certificate, if the NTM finds a valid certificate, the verifier will accept. But shouldn't the verifier reject my invalid certificate? In other words, I don't see my (potentially invalid) certificate being used anywhere in the equivalence proof.

Comment: You don't construct an NTM. The NTM is fixed once and for all. A certificate is an auxiliary input to the machine. A certificate is valid for an input if the machine accepts. That's it.

Comment: I suppose I may be misunderstanding the backwards implication outlined here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/58155/51868 - what's primarily confusing me is the fact that the certificate provided as auxiliary input seems to be irrelevant to whether the verifier accepts or not. It will accept any certificate iff the NTM can find a valid certificate for input $x$. In other words, we have the verifier and NTM – verifier takes certificate and defers to the NTM without passing the certificate to it. If NTM finds a valid certificate, verifier accepts. Else, it rejects.

Comment: I suggest forgetting about that answer and focusing on my answer. After you understand this answer, you will be able to understand that answer. Focus on the definitions.

Comment: So here's what I get from your answer, which makes sense. A verifier takes a certificate, which the NTM reads as input, and checks to see if it accepts or rejects. That makes total sense, because the NTM's accepting or rejecting depends on the certificate. But from the other answer, a verifier takes a certificate $c_e$ and the NTM guesses another certificate $c_d$ which may or may not be the same one that the verifier took as input. So even if $c_e$ is invalid, if the NTM can find a valid $c_d$, it will accept. It seems like the two explanations conflict.

Comment: You're not understanding the other answer correctly. It's not helpful to you, so I suggest ignoring it.

Comment: Would you mind explaining though where I'm misunderstanding? I've seen the same explanation used in other contexts, and the essence of this question was to clear up where I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: That answer is really the same as mine, only presented differently. With this in mind, you should be able to understand the other answer. I can't help you any further.

Comment: I think my confusion is stemming from the fact that yours talks about the NTM reading from a certificate passed to the verifier as auxiliary input and his answer talks about the NTM guessing just any valid certificate, not necessarily the one passed to the verifier. It seems like those two are fundamentally very different. Nevertheless, I appreciate your effort and I hope I can find some resource that clears up the confusion I'm having.